# Media Query for tablets landscape Only

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i am writing some twitter bootstrap code. I know how to target smartphones, tablet portrait desktop. But i have problem with tablet landscape. Its galaxy tab and resolution 1280px. But then if i target that resolution its changed on desktop also (if monitor have that resolution). can i target 1280px but only for tablet?

All other resolutions are working properly.

thanks.

## Mobile

only screen and (min-width: 480px)

## Tablet

only screen and (min-width: 768px)

## Desktop

only screen and (min-width: 992px)

## Huge

only screen and (min-width: 1280px)

Answer (score 0):

You can target landscape orientation only with following media query :

```
/* Landscape only for iPad / Tablet ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Your Styles here */
}
```

For Retina iPad

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) 
{ 
    /* STYLES GO HERE */
}
```

Comment: Yeah i tried that but it affect desktop also.Dont know why.